# Dictionary Iteration Python

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python.

Dictionary has multiple values.

```
dc = {1:['2', '3'], 2:['3'], 3:['3', '4']}
```

If you iterate over 'dc' you find there are three occurrences of '3'. First occurrence is in 1:['2','3'].
I would like to iterate over dict so that

```
if first occurrence of '3' occurs:
  dosomething()

else occurrence of '3' afterwards:#i.e. 2nd time, 3rd time....
  dosomethingelse()
```

How can I do this in Python

Thank you.

Comment: Since the dict is not ordered, what do you mean by 'first' occurrence of '3'?

Comment: p.s. naming your variable `dict` is a bad idea because you shadow the builtin

Comment: Thanks Wim. I am not sure if it is possible. There are three occurrences of 3, what I mean is 1:['2', '3'] in this, 3 appears 1st time

Comment: You should define what you mean by "first".  A dictionary doesn't have an intrinsic order.  Do you mean dict[x] contains '3' where x is the smallest value?

Comment: @Pujan Srivastava: Please **update** the question to contain **all** the details.  A long list of comments is a terrible thing.  You created the question, you can update it to make it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also keep a count of the times the element has been seen. Use a dict for this, and increment with each sighting:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dc = {3:['3', '4'], 1:['2', '3'], 2:['3']}
de={}

def do_something(i,k):
    print "first time for '%s' with key '%s'" % (i,k)

def do_somethingelse(i,j,k):
    print "element '%s' seen %i times. Now with key '%s'" % (i,j,k) 

for k in sorted(dc):
    for i in dc[k]:
        if i not in de:
            de[i]=1
            do_something(i,k)
        else:
            de[i]+=1
            do_somethingelse(i,de[i],k)
```

As others have said, dictionaries do not have the same order necessarily as the insertion or code listing. You can just sort the keys (with to `sorted(dc)`) to distinguish 'first' vs subsequent if this is the same as sort order. This method is easily extended to 'do_somthing' based on how *many* times the item has been seen.

Output:

```
first time for '2' with key '1'
first time for '3' with key '1'
element '3' seen 2 times. Now with key '2'
element '3' seen 3 times. Now with key '3'
first time for '4' with key '3'
```

Alternatively:

```
r=[]
for k in sorted(dc):
    print dc[k]
    if '3' in dc[k]:
        r.append("'3' number {} with key: {}".format(len(r)+1,k))
```

produces:

```
["'3' number 1 with key: 1", "'3' number 2 with key: 2", "'3' number 3 with key: 3"]
```

The list `r` will have the 3 strings in the order that the keys of `dc` are sorted in, then just iterate over the sequence `r`.

And if you are just looking for the 'first' `3` then the rest, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l=[i for sub in [dc[k] for k in sorted(dc)] for i in sub if i == '3']
>>> l
['3', '3', '3']
>>> l[0]
'3'
>>> l[1:] #all the rest...
```

Comment: I think he is looking for the first list containing '3', not all the '3''s in sort order...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the values in the dict are the lists:

```
foundThree = False
for key, val in dc.items():
    if '3' in val and not foundThree:
        foundThree = True
        # doSomething()
    elif '3' in val:
        # doSomethingElse()
    else:
        # doAnotherThing()
```

---

Edit (update for your comments about finding the first '3' in the list which is the value of a dict item) - this should work:

```
for key, val in dc.items():
    foundThree = False
    for n in val:
        if n == '3' and not foundThree:
            foundThree = True
            # doSomething()
        elif n == '3': 
            # doSomethingElse()
        else:
            # doAnotherThing()
```

Comment: you should set foundThree somewhere.

Comment: @wim Just noticed I forgot to set it to True after it evaluates.  Thanks!

Comment: This is good.  But.  True/False flags almost always turn into counters.  You should consider using `threeCount=0`; `threeCount += 1` and `if '3' in val and threeCount == 0:` so that expansion is handled more gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

Most of what you're asking for is pretty straightforward, the only part I can see you having trouble with is determining if the number 3 occurs after the first element.

You can do this with:

```
list[1:]
```

For instance:

```
>>> 3 in [1,2,4,5][1:]
False
>>> 3 in [3,1,2,4][1:]
False
>>> 3 in [1,2,3,4][1:]
True
```

Here's something that should work:

```
dc = {1:['2', '3'], 2:['3'], 3:['3', '4']}

def dosomething(): print 'something'

def dosomethingelse(): print 'something else'

for key,value in dc.items():
  if value[0] == '3':
    dosomething()
  elif '3' in value[1:]:
    dosomethingelse()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dict_ = {1:['2', '3'], 2:['3'], 3:['3', '4']}

def dosomething():
  print 'doing something'

def dosomethingelse():
  print 'doing something else'

three_handler = dosomething
for v in dict_.values():
  for three in [x for x in v if x == '3']:
    three_handler()
    three_handler = dosomethingelse
```

Output:

```
doing something
doing something else
doing something else
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use an if statement to check if the 3 is the first occurrence.

```
d = {1:['2', '3'], 2:['3'], 3:['3', '4']}

def doSomething():
   print('ds')

def doSomethingElse():
   print('dse')

for key,value in d.iteritems():
   do = doSomething
   for item in value:
      if item == '3':
         do()
         do = doSomethingElse
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below will give you an idea on how to do it.
This will work in single thread execution environment.

For more information start at python docs and [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/)

```
firstInstance = False
for k in mydict.keys():
  obj = mydict.get(k)
  for i in range(len(obj)):
    value = obj[i]
    if value == 3 and firstInstance:
       doSomething()
       firstInstance = True
    else:
       doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: This will give you a idea in how to do it if you come from Java side.      @chown's answer is a better pythonic approach

Comment: `for i in range(len(obj))` is rarely appropriate.  It's certainly not appropriate here.

Comment: @S.Lott Please share the correct way to do this because I have been using the same approach to iterate over list objects. BTW I have recently started working on python and i find it extremely good for creating backend tasks and creating scripts that analyze data.

Comment: `for i in range(len(obj)): value = obj[i]` === `for value in obj`:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'first' is as sorted by the dictionary's keys, this works:

```
>>> dc = {1:['2', '3'], 2:['3'], 3:['3', '4']}
>>> [dc[k] for k in sorted(dc) if '3' in dc[k]][0]
['2', '3']
>>> [dc[k] for k in sorted(dc) if '3' in dc[k]][1:]
[['3'], ['3', '4']]
```